# pgp pass phrase not working in enigmail but does in command line

Tags: macos, thunderbird, pgp

Hi I've been strugling with this issue of pass phrase and due to the amount of mail I have encrypted, I can't seriously change my pass phrase.

Here's the issue : Enigmail don't recognize my pass phrase while using this command it does :
    echo "1234" | gpg --no-use-agent -o /dev/null --local-user  -as - && echo "The correct passphrase was entered for this key"

it promps for my pass phrase and even with a copy & paste i have the successful messagge :
    The correct passphrase was entered for this key

But when i paste it in enigmail@TB I always have the not recognized pass phrase message with the pink band message...
any clue  ?

Comment: Changing your _passphrase_ (which encrypts your private key) does not change the _decrypted_ key – you can still read all old mail after changing it. The command you entered will not verify your key, neither does it read the pass phrase from stdin without explicit option set to do so, nor does it do anything at all. Can you _sign_ a message?

Comment: @Jens No I can't sign a message. I just used this command to verify my passphrase. ok for changing my pass phrase but I'm wondering if it has anything to do with my pass phrase at all actually. I think changing my pass phrase won't do any good.

Comment: I think this got migrated from SO, but the accounts weren't associated - Could you use the contact us link at the bottom to request this question be attributed to your account (I think it should be under account merger) so that you can comment, edit, and do all the other shiny things a post owner can?

Comment: As I already wrote, the command you've been running is not doing anything reasonable at all, especially not verifying your passphrase.